# Using custom key in firestore Vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am new at using cloud firestore and Vue.
I am trying to use custom key, instead of it's generated Id.
I tried using **set()**

But, received error:

> set() is not a function

Can someone help out, how to use it in Vue?
Thank you in advance

Comment: We'll need a lot more context to be able to help you. [ask] [mcve]

Comment: But what else content you need?

Comment: All i need help is in, how to use custom key in google cloud firestore

Comment: The immediate need is to fix the error you're seeing in regards to `set()`, but your question does not show any code, so we can't help you fix it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. As explained above, you need to share all the possible elements that allow someone that does not know your problem to understand it. In particular the full code that generate the problem. On which object you call `set()` for example?

Comment: The first sample in the [documentation on adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) shows how to specify the document key yourself. If that doesn't work for you, edit your question to include the [minimal, standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a ready project and imported the JS SDK and the firestore package:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

First, declare a reference to a collection

```
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('cars')
```

Then, you can set a new document passing an object to the set() function

```
ref.doc('my_custom_key').set({color: 'red'})
```